# Prometheus python client error Address already in use

Tags: python, monitoring, prometheus

I'm running a web app with address 127.0.0.1:5000 and am using the python client library for Prometheus. I use `start_http_server(8000)` from the example in their [docs](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) to expose the metrics on that port. The application runs, but I get `[Errno 48] Address already in use` and the localhost:8000 doesn't connect to anything when I try hitting it.

If I can't start two servers from one web app, then what port should I pass into `start_http_server()` in order to expose the metrics?

There is nothing already running on either port before I start the app.

Answer (score 4):

When flask's `debug` mode is set to `True`, the code reloads after the flask server is up, and a bind to the prometheus server is been called a second time

Set flask app `debug` argument to `False` to solve it

Comment: Perfoect. Thanks for this. wouldnt have identified by myself for sure. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

Some other process is utilizing the port (8000). To kill the process that is running on the port (8000), simply find the process_id [pid] of the process.

```
lsof -i :8000
```

This will show you the processes running on the port 8000 like this:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 21271 hashed    3u  IPv4 1430288      0t0  TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
```

You can kill the process using the kill command like this:

```
sudo kill -9 21271
```

Recheck if the process is killed using the same command

```
lsof -i :8000
```

There should be nothing on the stdout.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because you are restarting the server again on the port 8000.

To resolve this I created a function which will create the server after assuring the previous server or the port can be used.

You can look at https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/155, here the same case is addressed

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline

Answer (score -1):

Port 8000 does not need to have a web server running on it for it to be already in use. Use your OS command line to find the process that is using up the port then kill it. If a service is also running that causes it to get spawned again, disable that process.

A simpler solution would be to use another port instead of 8000.

**EDIT:** Looks like it is a bug in Prometheus. [Github Issue](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/155)

Comment: There is nothing running on 8000 until I start this process.

Comment: @ralphie9224 I see... looks like you have found a bug. This is a persisting issue in Prometheus. They are still working on fixing it. Here is the conversation  [Pull Request](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/155)

Answer (score -1):

you cannot run two http servers on the same thread.
I don't know why but the implementation of the prometheus_client doesn't runs the server on a separate thread.
my solution is

```
import logging.config
import os

import connexion
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from prometheus_client import start_http_server

app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./')
app.add_api('swagger.yml')


# If we're running in stand alone mode, run the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ThreadPool(1)
    pool.apply_async(start_http_server, (8000, ))  # start prometheus in a different thread
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True) . # start my server
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your 8000 port is occupied. You can change it to another port, such as 8001